# Изменение размера блоков на флексах

Tags: html, css, css3, html5, flexbox

Имеется проект https://mihinov.github.io/ 
При уменьшении окна я планировал, что блок `.half__row` с двумя `img` будет сужаться, но на картинке ниже, видно, что ничего не происходит, я пробовал добавлять `.half__row` значения `max-width: 100%;` и `height: auto;`, но всё равно ничего не уменьшается правильно.
[image]

Также, при уменьшении всё сужается по первой картинке в блоке `.half__row`, как будто только первую картинку видит браузер.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Меню не позволяет сделать страницу уже. Она просто масштабируется после того как упрется в меню. https://i.stack.imgur.com/igW1j.png

Comment: меню в `header` не должно на это влиять, т.к. у `header {position: absolute}`, я даже пробовал задавать `display: none` `header` и меню.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Оберните ваши картинки в `div` или пропишите правильные стили для картинок.

```css
.container {
  max-width: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: auto;
}
.row {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
}
.row + .row {
  margin-top: 25px;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x200">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200">
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/450x200"></div>
    <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/250x200"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!